# Can't set col_types manually in R with read_excel

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to read the Oxford stringacy index covid data (https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data). The data that I have is not the latest version, the data now has four additional columns, but I think if you look at it you will understand my problem.

I want to specify the data type for each of the columns, like in `col_types_owid_covid_data`. However, despite trying to do that with `col_types  = col_types_owid_covid_data`, `read_excel` tries to guess the data type for me. For instance the column `hosp_patients_per_million` gets converted to a `logi` when it should be numeric, just a specified.

What am I doing wrong?

Code below.

```
    library(readxl)
    library(reshape2)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plyr)
    library(svglite)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggExtra)
    library(ggthemes)
    library(ggpubr)
    library(openxlsx)
    library(scales)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(Hmisc)
    library(devtools) #needed for the GitHub installation
    
    main_directory = "where I put my file"
    
    input_directory = paste0(main_directory, "Input/")
    #------------------------------------
    
    col_types_owid_covid_data <- c("text",
    "text",
    "text",
    "date",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "text",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric",
    "numeric")
    
    #-----------Imports the raw data needed for the analysis----------------
    owid_covid_data <- as.data.frame(read_excel(paste0(input_directory, "owid-covid-data.xlsx"), sheet = "Data"),
                                     col_types  = col_types_owid_covid_data)
```

Comment: You are passing the `col_types` argument to `as.data.frame` rather than `read_excel`, try moving the parenthesis after `"Data"` to the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not see that myself, been trying for hours to understand what I did wrong...